# Color intervals according to categorical column

Tags: colors, bokeh

I have a Dataframe with three columns named 'activity' 'start' 'end'

I have plotted a basic graph with 'start' and 'stop' times.

```
cds=ColumnDataSource(df)
p=figure(x_axis_type='datetime', height=100, width=500, sizing_mode='scale_width', title='Prediction Graph')
p.yaxis.minor_tick_line_color=None

p.quad(left='Start', right='End', top=1, bottom=0, source=cds)

output_file('PredictionGraph.html')
show(p)
```

I'd like to color the intervals according to which activity it is. How can this be done?
Thanks in advance, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need only to add to your DataFrame `df` a column (e.g with the name `color`) with the color information (this can be a string with a color name or hex) and the you pass this information to your `p.quad(..., color='color')`.

**Minimal Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'start':[1,2,3], 
    'end':[1.1,2.2,3.3], 
    'activity':['a', 'a', 'b'], 
    'color':['red','blue','#F2583E']
})

p=figure(height=100, width=500)
p.quad(left='start', right='end', color='color', top=1, bottom=0, source=df)

show(p)
```

[image: quad example with color information]